# saving C structure in file problem!

Tags: c, file, save, struct

I am trying to save my structure in a file.txt. I have found the following code for saving, but the problem is that I want every `q[i]` to be saved in a different line in the file! I cannot modify the code.

```
void WriteFile(struct car* q )
{
    printf("Attempting to write...");
   FILE* fp = 0;
   char* buffer = 0;
   int i=0;

   /* allocate */
   buffer = malloc ( 150 );
   bzero( buffer, 150 );

   /* copy the data to a string */

   snprintf( buffer, 150, "%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%d/%d/%d\t%d/%d/%d\t%d/%d/%d\n",q->name,q->numberplate,q->km,q->phonenumber,q->overall_cost,q->paid_cost,q->dateIn->day,q->dateIn->month,q->dateIn->year,q->dateServiced->day,q->dateServiced->month,q->dateServiced->year,q->dateOut->day,q->dateOut->month,q->dateOut->year); 
   printf("\n"); 

   fp = fopen("arxeio3.txt", "a" );
   fputs( buffer, fp );
   fputs("\n",fp);

   free( buffer );
   fclose( fp );
}
```

Comment: Why can you not modify the code?

Comment: Check the return of fopen(): `if (!fp) printf("error opening file!\n");`

Comment: Even if i put \n in "snprintf(...)" or even if i enter fputs("\n",fp) my data are being saved in the same line!!!

Comment: are you sure you're compiling?

Comment: @karlphilip...yes...my mistake..i didn't check the return of fopen(), but still my data are saved in one line
@Nathan Fellman yes..i am compiling...and the file arxeio3.txt is created...with my data in...but all in one line!!!!!

Comment: Why bother with `snprintf` here?  Why not use `fprintf` after you open the file?

Comment: `fputs("\n",fp);` should take care of the newline. What program are you using to see the output file?

Answer (score 0):

This code first puts all the data into a string with snprintf() then dumps that string into a file. So to change the delimiter of the output you have to change the format string passed to snprintf(). Notice how the fields are currently separated either by tabs (\t) or /. Those have to be replaced by newlines.
If you're on Windows try "\r\n" as well if that doesn't work.

Comment: When you say to change the format string passed to snprintf() you mean doing something like a loop q[i].dateIn->day etc????? I nead the different fields to be seperated by tabs but...i need sometinh like this: 
q[0].name     q[0].numberplate ................... ("n")
q[1].name     q[1].numberplate ..................

Comment: Then write just that. for example "%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n%.2f\t%.2f\t%d..." (note the newline in there)

Answer (score 0):

Do you forget to loop over your car collection? Have you passed the car to `WriteFile` like this:

```
struct car[MAX_CAR];
int numberOfCar=0;

... // code to fill in car and update numberOfCar

for(i=0;i<numberOfCar;++i)
  WriteFile(&car[i]);
```

There is nothing wrong with your `WriteFile` implementation except that the buffer length `150` maybe not enough

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are viewing your results with an editor that prefers \r\n to just newline (\n). Try adding \r (CR) before the NL.